# How to use more_clear_headers with NginX Docker image

Tags: docker, nginx

I have nginx up and running with [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx). Inside nginx.conf I would like to add the following

```
more_clear_headers 'Server';
more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';
```

After that it stopped working. Apparently this is provided by a module called `nginx-plus-module-headers-more`. I have a Dockfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt update && apt install -y iputils-ping wget

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

As this container is already running, is connected a bash an executed the following commands:

```
#> apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

#> apt  install -y libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: nginx : Conflicts: nginx-common but 1.18.0-6.1+deb11u3 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
#>
```

At this point I get the impression that I have taken a wrong turn. Any suggestions how I should install this module?

`

Answer (score 1):

***Note:** This is not a direct solution to your package dependency mismatch problem. But rather a workaround.*

The way I solved it is by using a different apt package to load in the `more_clear_headers` plugin. I used `nginx-extras` instead.

```
# Commenting out your current command
# apt install -y libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter

# Replacing with different package Use different package
apt install -y nginx-extras
```

Here's my [source](https://serverfault.com/a/766634/1053378)